# Issue with creating DSL syntax

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following code:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  def foo
    a = bar
    puts a
  end
  def bar(str="qwe")
    str
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end
end

class B
  include A
  def bar(str="rty")
    str
  end
end

B.new.foo #=> "rty"
```

I wish class `B` to look like this:

```
class B
  include A
  bar "rty"
end

B.new.foo #=> rty
```

or

```
class B
  include A
  HelperOptions.bar "rty"  # HelperOptions class should be in module A
end

B.new.foo #=> rty
```

I tried using `define_method`, `class_eval`, and `initialize`. How can be implemented syntax `bar 'rty'` or `HelperOptions.bar 'rty'` and what shall be done in module `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question properly you want to define a class method `A.bar` that defines an instance method `B#bar` that returns it's argument, you can do it like this:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  def foo
   puts bar
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def bar(str)
      define_method(:bar) { str }
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
  bar 'rty'
end

B.new.bar
# => "rty"

B.new.foo
# Output: rty
```

Comment: Many thanks, It is what I'm looking for. What about second variant with HelperOptions.bar? How can I define 'bar' method for class HelperOptions in module A to use syntax class B; include A; HelperOptions.bar 'rty'; end

Comment: If you want to implement the call `HelperOptions.bar` you have to pass `self` (i.e. the class `B`) to the `HelperOptions.bar` method so you can call `B.send(:define_method, :bar) do ...`. I wouldn't recommend it.